# Using a single connection for multiple webforms and single database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am creating a project with multiple webforms using asp.net and C#. In it, I wish to open a connection string on my first form to connect my webpage with MySql database and I wish to use the same connection string for further webforms which are interlinked and then close the connection at last form. Amongst all this, my database table remains the same throughout the execution. How can I do that? Since I am new to asp.net and C#, I wish to have a detailed answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You don't "open a connection string". You open a connection using a connection string. And connections shouldn't be held open for long periods of time or used across different requests etc. Open them right when you need them, close them immediately afterwards. The best way to do this is to wrap them in a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: @mason Yes thats what I meant to say. And my problem is that I want to retrieve data from the user from multiple webforms and store it as a single record entry in MySql database. So for that purpose, I need to keep my connection open untill the user reachers the final webform. Is there any other way to do so except that of keeping the connection open for such a long time duration? And, thanks for your friendly gesture!

Comment: Of course. You persist the data in memory. Or you store it in the database and then update it with subsequent commands (in different connections). Like I said, connections shouldn't be held open for long periods of time or used across different requests.

Comment: @mason yes I get your point Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

u can save ur connection in web.config and get in ur code with configuration namespace.

```
<add name="DbEntities" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=db;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and add this to your codes :

```
string s=  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
     ConnectionStrings["DbEntities"].ConnectionString;
```

i think u need add this refrence to ur project :

```
System.Configuration
```